# Online database slows down the performance of application (Java:Netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I have built an application in Java using Netbeans and connected to a hosted database. I have purchased hosting for 1 year and uploaded my database at [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.co/). My problem is that the application is working fine on localhost, but when I connect it the online database performance is very low. It takes about 1 second processing/executing each query,  making the application less useable. Please can somebody guide me through this - what should I do to make it work as well as it does on localhost?

Thanks

Comment: Can you measure ping latency? If your application is more chatty than bulky the latency may ruin performance whatewer you would do. Is deploying the application closer to the base an option?

Comment: how can I measure ping latency?

Comment: Where did you purchase your hosting?

Comment: http://freesqldatabase.com/